# How to set Floating Action Button image to fill the button?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, floating-action-button, material-components-android

Usually icons are set for floating action buttons, but I need to set an image, so I can make a circular image.

I added it to the project (using Android Studio-> New -> Image Asset), but the image didn't fill the entire button:

[image]

My xml:

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/run_menu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:visibility="visible"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#DA4336"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="#E75043"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
    fab:fab_shadowColor="#66000000"
    fab:fab_showShadow="true"
    fab:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    fab:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    fab:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    fab:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    fab:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    fab:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
    fab:menu_fab_label="Choose an action"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/store"
        fab:fab_label="Store" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? How should it be properly made?

Comment: I would ask the author, but apparently the library is abandoned. https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues

Answer (score 27):

The solution is `app:maxImageSize = "56dp"` property set to your FAB.

1. Have an image or vector asset, preferably in perfect circle shape and perfectly fit to canvass (no empty margins).
2. Know the actual [size of Floating Action Bar (FAB)](https://www.google.com/search?q=size+of+fab&rlz=1C1CHBF_enPH840PH840&oq=size+of+fab&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - Default (56 x 56dp) or Mini (40 x 40dp).
3. XML Code thusly:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
   android:src="@drawable/perfect_fit_circle_image"
   app:maxImageSize="56dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: this method works but now the image is bigger and does not go circle shape like it's parent FAB. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Set the following property  for the FAB

`android:scaleType="center"`

if that does not work try using property

`app:fabSize="mini"`

Comment: android:scaleType="center" made the button disappear
app:fabSize="mini" didn't do anything

Answer (score 3):

With the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), according to the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md#attributes), you can use the attribute **`app:maxImageSize`**.

You can use a custom dimension, but you can also refer to these defined dimensions.

```
<dimen name="design_fab_size_mini">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_fab_size_normal">56dp</dimen>
```

Just use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/design_fab_size_normal"
        ../>
```

Here the result with the standard dimension (`<dimen name="design_fab_image_size">24dp</dimen>`) and the `design_fab_size_normal`.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set scale for the float button in xml

```
android:scaleX="2.0"
```

Or you can do it programmaticaly:

```
someButton.setScaleX(2.0f);
someButton.setScaleY(2.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting a rounded png image, work around for this is to extend the floatingActionButton class then override the on onMeasure method and set the padding to 0, and scaleType To centerCrop

```
public class FloatingImageButton extends FloatingActionButton {


public FloatingImageButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FloatingImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);


}
}
```

**xml sample**

```
    <com.tabz.app.FloatingImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Override image size dimension for nested image in FAB by adding below line in dimens.xml

`<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_fab_image_size">56dp</dimen>`

```
     (I used 56dp cause fab size in guidelines is 56dp)
```

2. add  `app:tint="@null"` and `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in FAB.