# Can't create round button with FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

When I use `FloatingActionButton` button it isn't created correctly.

[image: FloatingButton]

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"/>
```

What should I do to display the button correctly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Floating Action Button image to fill the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495764/how-to-set-floating-action-button-image-to-fill-the-button)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to switch to the new material components. Other than that, this is what works for me. Did you enable the appcompat styles for your app?

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/round_add_white_24" />
```

Comment: With material components i have same result. Appcompat styles enable... But i created new project and button works in it, very strange...

Comment: Problem is solved. I had a problem with appcompat versions.